# nodejs passport ldapauth "Cannot read 'on' property of undefined"

Tags: node.js, ssl, ldap, passport.js

I'm trying to authenticate to an LDAP server using passport-ldapauth and express.

The authentication using an ldap url (ldap://myserver...) works OK, but with ldaps I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
    at setupSocket (...\ldapauth-fork\node_modules\ldapjs\lib\client\client.js:111:14)
    at Client._connect (...\ldapauth-fork\node_modules\ldapjs\lib\client\client.js:742:3)
    at new Client (...\ldapauth-fork\node_modules\ldapjs\lib\client\client.js:247:22)
    at Object.createClient (...\ldapauth-fork\node_modules\ldapjs\lib\client\index.js:60:12)
    at new LdapAuth (...\ldapauth-fork\lib\ldapauth.js:129:28)
    at handleAuthentication (...\passport-ldapauth\lib\passport-ldapauth\strategy.js:140:10)
    at Strategy.authenticate (...\passport-ldapauth\lib\passport-ldapauth\strategy.js:175:33)
    at attempt (...\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:341:16)
    at authenticate (...\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:342:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (...\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
```

My code is, basically, this:

```
  ...
  passport.use(new LdapStrategy({
  server: {
    url: 'ldaps://myserver:636',
    searchBase: '...',
    searchFilter: '(uid={{username}})',
    tlsOptions: {
        ca: [
            fs.readFileSync('myCAcert.pem')
    ]
   }
    },
    session: false,
    usernameField:'u',
    passwordField:'p'
  }, 
 function(user,  done) {
   console.log("Interna: \nOK");
    console.log("u:");
    console.log(user.cn);
   return done(null, user);
 }));

 app.use('/login',passport.authenticate('ldapauth', 
                 { session:false,                                        
                   successRedirect:'/accessed',
                   failureRedirect: '/accessfail' 
                  }
                 )); 

app.use('/accessed',function (req,res,next){
     res.send("User OK");
});

app.use('/accessfail',function (req,res,next){
       res.send("User MAL !!!!!!!");
 });

app.listen(3336);
```

My library versions are:

```
 express@4.11.2, passport@0.2.1,passport-ldapauth@0.3.0
```

Someone can help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Finally, I could solve the issue.

The ldapjs version used in ldapauth-fork, can't work with an ldaps url.

The solution was:

1. Delete the ldapjs from ldapauth-fork using in the node_modules directory under ldapauth-fork (under other node_modules directory under passport-ldap in the node_modules for my user !!!!!!) the following command:

   npm rm ldapjs
2. Install the new version from github using:

   npm install git://github.com/mcavage/node-ldapjs.git

FDO.

Comment: Same problem here. Thank you for the fix. See https://github.com/vesse/node-ldapauth-fork/pull/18

Answer (score 2):

This happens only with Node 0.12 and io.js when using SSL, see the [ldapjs issue](https://github.com/mcavage/node-ldapjs/issues/256). You can add dependency to the unreleased version in your projects `package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "ldapjs": "mcavage/node-ldapjs",
    "ldapauth-fork": "2.3.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: @Paul Should work without this nowadays with the latest versions, `ldapauth-fork` uses `ldapjs` 1.0.0.

Comment: good to know.  The version of passport-ldapauth I was using did not, however, so this led me down the right trail.